# how can I host a website using Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web

I currently have a lot of data record stored on amazon S3, and I am trying to build a dynamic website using these data. I know how to get data from databases like mySQL using php, but can I execute sql query directly on amazon S3? If I cann't, what is the right place I can put these data so that it is easy to load the data from S3 and also php-accessible?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

S3 is just used for storing files, I'm not sure how it would be used to store data records.  You can access the files and offer them for download from the website, or load them into memory on the server if its something like an sqlite database or something.  You probably want to look into using Amazon RDS instead of S3 for storing relational data.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is not a web server. It's for storing flat-files. There is no CPU.

If you want a web server that runs PHP, you should consider Amazon EC2 or AWS Elastic Beanstalk. If you need a MySQL server, you should check out Amazon RDS.